# Exponential family of distributions

Tags: statistics, exponential-function, self-learning, statistical-inference

A family of pdfs or pmfs is called an exponential family if

$$f(x|\theta) = h(x)c(\theta) \exp \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} w_{i}(\theta) t_{i}(x) \right)$$

so, I wonder if this distribution belongs to the exponential family:

$$f(x|\theta) = exp(\theta-x)$$

My guess is no because we cannot write it as above, am I correct?

Comment: Think about some of those functions being identically equal to $1$. Also think about a small value of $k$.

Comment: So is it possible that:
$$ h(x) = 1 $$
$$ c(\theta) = exp(\theta) $$
$$ w(\theta) = 1$$
$$ t(x)= -x $$

am i right or close ?

Comment: Yes, and $k=1$.